# Asp.net Chart Control getting disappeared

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have four chart controls on a single aspx page. On click of one chart next chart will appear so for that I have bind all the charts on click event. But on the click event of third chart, first chart is getting disappeared. All other click events are working fine. Below is the mentioned code:

```
protected void Chart3_Click(object sender, ImageMapEventArgs e)
{
    string pointData = e.PostBackValue.Split(';')[0];

    Session["pointvalue2"] = pointData;
    BindChart1();
    bindchart2();
    BindChart3();
    bindchart4();
}

  public void BindChart1()
    {

         DateTime fromdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtfromdate.Text);


        string sqlFormattedDate = fromdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
        Session["fromdate"] = sqlFormattedDate;



        DateTime todate = Convert.ToDateTime(txttodate.Text);
        string sqlFormattedDate1 = todate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");

        Chart1.Visible = true;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            conn.Open();
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select col2 as 'col2', col1 as 'col1',col3 as 'col3' from dbo.table where APPLICATION = 'test' and col1 BETWEEN @fromdate AND @todate group by MONTH(col1),col2", conn);


            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromdate", sqlFormattedDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@todate", sqlFormattedDate1);
                           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            gvreport.DataSource = rdr;
            gvreport.DataBind();


        }
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("severity", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Count", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Time", typeof(int)));

        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvreport.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Count"] = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Text);
            dr["severity"] = row.Cells[1].Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        DataTable ChartData = dt;
        Chart1.DataSource = dt;
        Session["dtTest"] = dt;

        // Set series members names for the X and Y values
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "severity";
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Count";

        // Data bind to the selected data source
        Chart1.DataBind();
        Chart1.Titles.Add("Chart");
        Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Disabled";
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].ToolTip = "Related_CI_Type: #VALX, Count: #VALY";
        foreach (Series series in Chart1.Series)
        {
            series.PostBackValue = "#SERIESNAME;#VALX;#VALY";
        }
        Chart1.Visible = true;

    }
```

Kindly suggest. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think there's not enough code for us to be able to help you. Could you maybe share the BindChart() code ?

Comment: @AntoineThiry I have added the code of BindChart().

Comment: there's nothing here which would obviously cause it. In fact you're setting it Visible twice, just to be extra sure! (Just kidding, that makes no difference, once is enough.) Does one of the other methods accidentally hide it - perhaps a typo or something? What about Page_Load, or one of the other three BindChart methods?